# No GUI when I boot Ubuntu

Tags: xorg, display-manager

When I start my laptop I get the GNU/GRUB boot loader which asks me to select an OS.  When I select Ubuntu I get the screen that asks me for my password, so I type it in but I just get a loading screen.  But if I press Ctrl+alt+F2 I get the command line interface which works fine.  Can't get the GUI to work though. What can I do?

Comment: When I start my Ubuntu partition it asks me for my password and when I type it I just get a loading screen and nothing else happens.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and GUI environment are you using, I am assuming 16.04 and Unity. Is it correct?

Comment: It's actually 14.04 LTS

Comment: And the default desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:
I am assuming your Unity has been misconfigured or gone wrong. Try the below steps:

Login into Ubuntu.

Open a terminal by hitting Ctrl + Alt +  or in your case Ctrl + Alt + F2

Run this command:

`gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1 unity --reset`

Restart, this should work.

Ref: [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)